# maximal bound for OU process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I would like to obtain the finiteness of the following expectation involving the OU process:

let $X_t = e^{-\alpha t} x + (1-e^{-\alpha t}) \mu + e^{-\alpha t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha u} \hspace{1mm} dB_u $ ,
where $ x $ and $ \mu $ are fixed constants;

for $\lambda > 0$, we would like to show

$E[\hspace{1mm} \sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \hspace{1mm} e^{-\lambda t}\mid X_t \mid \hspace{1mm}] < \infty $.

A quick observation is that it is enough to show

$E[\hspace{1mm} \sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \hspace{1mm} e^{-(\lambda + \alpha) t} \mid \int_{0}^{t} e^{\alpha u} \hspace{1mm} dB_u \mid \hspace{1mm}] < \infty $.

The above is a family of one dimensional Gaussian process; I am wondering if there is a direct argument available, or any existing inequality that would give us the desired bound.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to answer my own question.

We can take $\lambda = 0$.

Note that $e^{−αt} \int_{0}^t e^{\alpha u} \hspace{1mm} dB_u$ defines a local martingale (since the integrand is deterministic, hence predictable).

Now we finish the proof by applying the BDG inequality with $p=1$ for $t \in [0,T]$ with some fixed $T$, to obtain a bound of the supremum of the stochastic integral by the square root of its quadratic variation on $[0,T]$; noting that the bound can be made uniform over $T$; we conclude by sending $T $ to infinity.

Comment: The stochastic integral $\int_0^t e^{\alpha u}dB_u$ *is*  a martingale, but when you tack on that extra factor $e^{-\alpha t}$, it's no longer even a local  martingale. In fact, if you write $Y_t:=e^{-\alpha t}\int_0^t e^{\alpha u}dB_u$ then by Ito's formula,
$$
Y_t = B_t-\alpha \int_0^t Y_s ds.
$$